# Problems serving static files on development server only

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I'm having trouble serving static files on my development server.  I have it configured as follows.  This is in my settings.py file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
if socket.gethostname() == 'production_server':
  STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/html/static/"
else:
  STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
```

I find a couple things curious about this:

1. Everything works fine on the production server.
2. On the development server, I get 404 errors for my own files but not the admin files...

   ```
   http://localhost:8000/static/media/default.cssFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
   http://localhost:8000/static/media/javascript/pipe.jsFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
   http://localhost:8000/static/media/javascript/imdb_form.jsFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
   http://localhost:8000/static/media/pipe-img/wb-mpi-logo.pngFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
   http://localhost:8000/static/media/pipe-img/wb-mpi-logo-large.pngFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
   ```

...from this template...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}media/default.css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/css/forms.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}media/pipe-img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="icon" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}media/pipe-img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}media/javascript/pipe.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}media/javascript/imdb_form.js"></script> <!-- FUTURE:  call from IMDB widget? -->
```

Note that it's only complaining about the non-admin URLs.

Finally, I also noticed that if I run ./manage.py collectstatic, it collects only the admin files into my STATIC_ROOT directory, not my app's media files.  Futhermore, even if I wipe out the STATIC_ROOT directory, the admin links still work.

How can I work through those 404 errors and get all my static files served up properly?

Comment: Show us your PROJECT_DIR definition

Comment: It's `PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`, which translates to my app's directory.

Comment: Does it say anything in the server output/log about why the files are not found?

Answer (score 1):

Set your `STATICFILES_DIRS` variable in `settings.py` to contain the path to where the static assets are. This should bring them in when running `./manage.py runserver` with `DEBUG = True`

Also I would use environment vars to extend the tuple for `STATICFILES_DIRS`

```
if os.environ['deploy_type'] == 'prod':
    STATICFILES_DIRS += ("/var/www/html/static/",)
else:
    STATICFILES_DIRS += (os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),)
```

You can have your environment variables set as part of your deployment process and assist in having a flexible deployment process.

Sorry for the bit of a tangent and hope this helps :)